# How to get the first row per group?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have a query like this:

```
select count(1) num, business_id, category_id
from mytable
group by business_id, category_id
order by num desc
```

The result looks like this:

```
// res
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| num | business_id | category_id |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 22  | 5543        | 8           |
| 19  | 4352        | 8           |
| 13  | 3242        | 11          |
| 10  | 2132        | 11          |
| 7   | 6832        | 8           |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

Now I want to get the first row for each `category_id`. So it must be the biggest `num` and its `business_id`. So the expected result would be:

```
// expected res
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| num | business_id | category_id |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 22  | 5543        | 8           |
| 13  | 3242        | 11          |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your MySQL version support `ROW_NUMBER` + window function, you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the biggest `num` by `category_id`

**Query #1**

```
SELECT num,business_id,category_id
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY num desc) rn
    FROM (
        select count(1) num, business_id, category_id
        from mytable
        group by business_id, category_id
    ) t1
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

| num | business_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 5543 | 8 |
| 13 | 3242 | 11 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pEykEQKL1tX7veQo8q27pX/0)

Comment: I see, thank you .. I will check it out now .. just, what does `rn` stands for?

Comment: `rn` as alias for the result of the SELECT clause - presumably standing for row number as in: number of row.

Comment: @MartinAJ  `ROW_NUMBER` window function will make a number for the `order by` which means you can find the biggest `num` by that.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

Comment: I see @D-Shih, Thanks. Also, is it ok to use `t1` twice for two different tables alias?

Comment: @MartinAJ Because `ROW_NUMBER` can't be conditioned on where clause

Answer (score 3):

Use window functions `MAX()` to get the max `num` and `FIRST_VALUE()` to get the `business_id` of that max `num`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY category_id) num, 
       FIRST_VALUE(business_id) OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) business_id, 
       category_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY business_id, category_id
ORDER BY num DESC;
```